# Using Eval inside a IF statement and Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use Eval inside a IF Statement and Repeater.

I want to do something like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpRepeater">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <% if ((bool)Eval("A_Boolean"))
              { %>
                blah...
           <% } %>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

This code gives me the following error:

Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: I know I can use the DataBinding Event, but it seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval can be only used inside "binding" tag.

```
<%# Eval("A_Boolean") %>
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860#1a

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to simulate `if` statements like this (code goes within `ItemTemplate`).

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("A_Boolean") %>'>
    blah...
</asp:Panel>
```