# Displaying data conditionally within a user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, eval

Within an ASP.NET user control I have the line:

```
<div>Web: <a href="<%# Eval("Web") %>"><%# Eval("Web") %></a></div>
```

I'd like to change it so this HTML is only rendered if `Web` has a value.

I've tried wrapping `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Web") as string)` in server side script but [Eval can only be used inside a "binding" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080962/using-eval-inside-a-if-statement-and-repeater/1081003#1081003).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, what control contains the "Web" value? You could use the FindControl method in the code-behind to get its value.

Comment: @TenaciousImpy: The code is within a Repeater. `Web` is defined in the Repeater's data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a workaround, but you could have a hidden field in your ItemTemplate tag:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("web") %>' />
```

You could then set the 'runat' attribute of the div to 'server' and give the div an ID.

```
<div id="divWeb" runat="server" visible="false">Web: <a href="<%# Eval("Web") %>"><%# Eval("Web") %></a></div>
```

In your code-behind, you check whether or not `HiddenField1` is empty. If it's not empty, then set 'divWeb' `visible = true`.

The downside to this method is that the user could manually change the HiddenField1 value. However, if that's not a problem (security wise), then you could try this method.

**Update**
The code snippet below is from the inline section of [this site](http://web.archive.org/web/20080610160756/http://www.openmymind.net/index.aspx?documentId=8):

```
<asp:Repeater id="collectionRepeater" Runat="server">  
     <ItemTemplate>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OwnerId") %> - 
      <asp:literal ID="see" Runat="server" 
         Visible='<%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Pets.Count") > 0 %>'>
         see pets
      </asp:Literal>
      <asp:literal ID="nopets" Runat="server" 
        Visible='<%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Pets.Count") == 0 %>'>
          no pets
       </asp:Literal>
       <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

There are also alternative options in [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/302270/302270.aspx#302270)

Comment: @TenaciousImpy: That's a good idea as well. I just wish there was something inline that could be done!

Comment: @Alex - This post has two suggestions that could work:`http://forums.asp.net/p/302270/302270.aspx#302270`. Also, thanks to internet archiving :D, this page has an inline solution `http://web.archive.org/web/20080610160756/http://www.openmymind.net/index.aspx?documentId=8`

Comment: I tried the first link which was OK but then used the inline option from your second link on a label. This is the sort of thing I'm looking for. Perhaps you could put these links as an update to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, MVC was meant more for that type of logic in the page...  typically with web forms everything is done with code-behind...  Additionally, would you consider doing something like:

```
<div style='<%# ((Eval("Web") != null) ? "display" : "none") %>'>Web: <a href="<%# Eval("Web") %>"><%# Eval("Web") %></a></div>
```

Haven't tried this approach specifically, but I know tertiary (?:) works in this context, and so it seems logical that it could work....

Comment: @Brian: That would technically work but I'd prefer to render nothing. If only I could use MVC, unfortunately not an option.